# moving UIImageView form first tapped UIControl to second tapped UIControl

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, logic

I have 25 UIControls and 10 UIImageView. It looks like this:

[image]

Now the images are the UIImageVIews and the grids are the UIControls. What I want is when the user taps at a image and then taps at any of the grids (any blank grids of-course) the UIImageView is then removed from the current superView and added as the subView of the blank grid tapped. For example, if the user taps at the A1 grid first and then in the B2 grid, two actions occur,

1. UIImageView from A1 grid is removed,
2. UIImageView is added to B2 grid

This means when the user taps at the image at A1 grid and then taps at the B2 grid, the output window looks like this:

[image]

***EDIT***

So, at a time I need to have track for two UIControls:
1.which one is pressed first, and
2.which one is pressed second. 
And then remove the UIImageView from the first UIControl and add it to the second UIControl. I have tried giving the UIControls a tag like,

```
//....    
A1.tag = 1;
//...
-(void)a1ViewTapped:(id)sender
{
    int i = A1.tag;
    [self switch:i];
}
//...
-(void)switch:(int)_tag
{
    //....
    UIView *view = (UIView*)[self.view viewWithTag:_tag];

    [view removeFromSuperview];
    //...
}
```

By this I can track a single UIControl, but need to track two of them.
How can I accomplish this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIControl` inherits from `UIView`, so you can add a subview to your `UIControl` by calling `addSubview:`.

You can remove your `UIImageView` from the previous control by calling `removeFromSuperview` on the `UIImageView`

edit:

A very simple implementation would be to create a property that holds a reference to the selected `UIControl`. When the property is nil, then you are in selection mode. Touching up inside a control puts a reference to the control into the property. When the property is not nil, you are looking for a grid control in which to place the image.

You'll also need a way to keep track of whether your UIControl has one of the UIImageView instances as a subview. There are a number of ways to do that. One way would be to subclass `UIControl` to add a property to it that points to the UIImage it contains. Another way might be to simply examine the subviews of the UIControl to see if it contains one of the images in question. Another way would be to create some data structure to keep track of the positions of the images. How you do it is up to you, and the best way depends on the specifics of your implementation.

Just for the sake of discourse, let's assume you set up an `NSMutableDictionary` called `imageMap` that uses the tags of your UIControls as keys and sets references to the images as values. Then you could do something like:

```
-(void)selectGridControl:(UIView*)view
{
    if (selectedControl == nil)  // In this case nothing is selected
    {
        selectedControl = view;
    }
    else   // In this case we are moving the image to the new view
    {
        UIImageView *selectedImage = [imageMap objectForKey:selectedControl.tag];

        if (selectedImage != nil)
        {
            [selectedImage removeFromSuperview];
            [view addSubview:selectedImage];
            [imageMap removeObjectForKey:selectedControl.tag];
            [imageMap addObject:selectedImage forKey:view.tag];
            selectedControl = nil;
         }
     }
```

Initializing `imageMap` and handling cases when the destination control already has an image are left as exercises for the reader.

Comment: thanks for your reply,  i know i can call both addSubView and removeFromSuperView. but i am not being able to find out how can i accomplish the action through a method, please read the question again. when the user taps at a image and then taps at a empty grid the image form the first grid is removed and the same image is added to the grid tapped second. i need to have track of the grids tapped and which grid contains image and when to replace it.

Comment: So exactly what part are you having trouble with? Perhaps you could be more specific in your question and maybe post something you've already tried and explain what's not working.

Comment: how can i track the UIControls, i mean how can i track that which UIControl is tapped first and which control is tapped second and then how to interchange the UIImageView? i have tried giving the controls a tag(for example A1.tag = 1) and thus have accomplished to track a single UIControl, but in this case i need to track two controls at a time, which one is tapped first and which one is tapped second. can you help me with this?

Comment: I added a brief description of a way you could handle it. Sorry I don't have time for anything more detailed.